# AngularJS - does everything need to loaded on initial page load?

Tags: view, angularjs, single-page-application, partials

I am diving into JavaScript MVC with Angular and as I understand it, along with the initial shell page, all your scripts must be loaded on the initial page load. However, and correct me if I'm wrong, that would mean that a majority of your scripts being loaded could be entirely useless (i.e. you have view #1 showing and scripts for views #2 - #10 aren't needed yet)?

In my case, I have a fairly large web app, with a feed page, results page, product page, profile page, among others. It amounts to 10+ pages, and my current (the traditional) approach is loading scripts specific to each page on load. Now each page is a partial and I don't believe it's possible to load specific scripts with partials?

So, part of my question is if my statements are accurate. The other is whether or not my fear of suffering on initial page load are justified (especially for mobile devices for instance).

I really got into Angular in hopes to clean up my JavaScript with the MVC approach and did not plan on taking advantage of it as a single page application (I can forego the use of routing different partials into my view, right?). But now I'm not sure. I just want to get a better understanding of how it works before making the leap.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into AMD pattern with Require.JS (Works with any type of JS framework). There is a seed project with AngularJS + RequireJS.

Comment: With RequireJS, you will still end up loading all the modules that you'll ever use into your main module definition (since angular won't bootstrap until it sees all the parts). I think to get around this you would have to use the syntax like "define ['require', function(require) { dep1 = require("dependency_1"); dep2 = require("dep2"); .... }]. It's not worth it IMO. The Angular team says they have in their pipeline for 2.0. We can only hope their solutions works with RequireJS.